# Upgrading From .Net Web Api to .Net Core: localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently used the .Net Upgrade Assistant to upgrade my .Net Web API to a .Net Core API.

I am running into an issue where when I run the API it gives the following error:

```
This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

I have already installed the .Net Runtime and .Net SDKx64.

I am not sure if one of the older .Net Web files could be causing the issue.

Here is the Startup.cs:

```
namespace MediStockAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "*";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("*");
                                  });
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews(ConfigureMvcOptions)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                {
                    options.UseMemberCasing();
                });

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        private void ConfigureMvcOptions(MvcOptions mvcOptions)
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: According to your code snippet, it seems that your project is an mvc project but not an web api project. And what I mean is, if you feel your issue comes from the startup setting, you may create a new project and just compare the newly created one with your code above. Per my understanding, 500 error is more likely to be something wrong with the business code in your api, have you debug your code?

Comment: @TinyWang We ended up deciding to re-write the API and create a new .Net Core API. Your comment is right in assuming the issue was because the project was a .Net Web API and not a .Net Core API.